# Creating a userform that prints textbox input to specific spots in the document

Tags: performance, vba, loops, userform, undo-redo

I was working on a system in VBA word. The goal of the system is to replace several different words in a document with input from a text box. So far I have a userform with 12 different text boxes each containing input from a user to replace words in the document. I made a button in the userform to print all the input from the textboxes to the document. 
For each textbox I made the following code:

```
Sub FindAndReplaceAllStoriesHopefully()

Dim myStoryRange As Range

'
'
'Loop replaces everything with <KLANTNAAM> in the document
For Each myStoryRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With myStoryRange.Find
    .Text = "<KLANTNAAM>"
    .Replacement.Text = TextBox1.Value
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Do While Not (myStoryRange.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
    Set myStoryRange = myStoryRange.NextStoryRange
    With myStoryRange.Find
        .Text = "<KLANTNAAM>"
        .Replacement.Text = TextBox1.Value
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Loop
Next myStoryRange
```

So far I did this for all 12 textboxes and it works but it isn't smooth. The 
button upon getting clicked is calling the function with

```
Call FindAndReplaceAllStoriesHopefully
```

I have a few problems which I just cannot fix:

- Once the button is clicked and some textboxes are not filled by the user, the marked words like `<KLANTNAAM>` are still replaced and removed from the document.
- The performance of the macro is not great since the same code is copied 12 times.
- Once the button is clicked, there is no easy way for the user to undo mistakes typed in the userform since the results are already printed.

I was hoping to get some tips so I can finalize this application.

Comment: You can create a bookmark for each distinct value you want to populate, then create cross-references to each bookmark for every "repeat" of that value.  https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/word-repeating-text-within-a-document/  You can then populate each of the bookmarks with the text from your form (add a check for blank values!) and as long as you're careful not to delete the bookmarks while doing that, you can then come back later and make adjustments.  When the user re-opens your form you can pick up the text from each bookmark to populate the form with the "current" values.

Comment: Replacing text in a bookmark without deleting it: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/InsertingTextAtBookmark.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, i was indeed thinking about bookmarks aswell. however your last link suggests the subroutine with the code     UpdateBookmark(BookmarkToUpdate As String, TextToUse As String) where TextToUse has to be the value of the TextBoxes, i cant seem to figure out how to dim it so it uses the value.

Comment: Nevermind, i made it work using the click function of a button i dimmed the names of the textboxes to strings and gave them the value of that textbox.  i then called the function with Call UpdateBookmark("bookmarkstring", dimmed string of the textbox) But i cant seem to figure out how a check for blank values would fit in here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim numBlank As Long, n As Long, txt As String
    Dim bookMarkName As String

    numBlank = Me.CountBlanks
    If numBlank > 0 Then
        If MsgBox(numBlank & " entries are blank!. Continue?", _
                         vbExclamation + vbOKCancel) <> vbOK Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    For n = 1 To 4
        txt = Me.Controls("Textbox" & n).Text
        bookMarkName = "BOOKMARK" & n
        FindAndReplaceAllStoriesHopefully bookMarkName, txt
    Next n

End Sub

Function CountBlanks() As Long
    Dim n As Long, b As Long
    b = 0
    For n = 1 To 4
        If Len(Me.Controls("Textbox" & n).Text) = 0 Then
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Next n
    CountBlanks = n
End Function
```